# C pointer being freed was not allocated (even though I malloc'd it, and that's all this program does)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm writing a C program on my mac and I made something basic, but I got this error. I have a struct with a char pointer in it to hold a short description. In my main class I made a pointer to this struct and then another for the char pointer within the struct. When I free the char pointer in the struct, my terminal throws out some error message about a pointer being freed that was not allocated. The error is not present if I comment that line out, so I'm pretty sure it's that line. I'll include the code causing this odd issue.

```
Chair *chair = (Chair*)malloc(sizeof(Chair));
chair->color = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
chair->color = "blue";
printf("This chair is %s", chair->color);
free(chair->color);
free(chair);
return 0;
```

When I searched for this, it always came to user error of not mallocing or "double free errors". I'm pretty sure I used malloc and that there isn't a glaringly obvious problem in those 6 lines.

Comment: `chair->color = "blue";` : `chair->color` rewrite by string literal 's address. (it was not malloc'd address).

Comment: I also just noticed that I don't even need to malloc "strings". My example was so basic that I forgot the basics... I can just use char *string = "some text";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of errors.

1. In the line:

   ```
   chair->color = "blue";
   ```

   you are assigning `chair->color` to point to some memory that you didn't get from `malloc`. Then you are trying to `free` it later.

   You'll need `strcpy` to accomplish what you are trying.

   ```
   strcpy(chair->color, "blue");
   ```
2. In order to copy `"blue"`, you have to have a string that has at least 5 characters - 4 for the letters and 1 for the terminating null character. You need to use:

   ```
   chair->color = malloc(N); // Where N > 4.
   ```

   Don't cast the return value of `malloc`. It is known to be problematic if you do. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

   You also don't need to use `sizeof(char)`. It is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: I think I just realized the problem. I am coming from a c++ environment, and malloc always gave a void pointer error if it wasn't cast. The chair->color = "blue"; was also doable in that environment. I was writing more c++ than I realized. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 3):

```
chair->color = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
chair->color = "blue";
```

To store a 4-char string, you need 5 bytes. 1 extra for the ending `\0`.
Also, to assign a string, you should use `strcpy()`.

```
strcpy(chair->color, "blue");
```